# How to import terraform policy attachment?

Tags: terraform

Our main goal is to move some resources to a different terraform state fle. I am trying to import a policy attachment of a resource ,however seems like it does not support importing of policy attachment . i am getting an error.

What is the other alternative if it does not support?

i am trying to import this policy

```
 + aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.gitlab_as_attach
      id:                                                <computed>
      policy_arn:                                        "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:policy/gitlab_as_policy"
      role:                                              "gitlab_prod"
```

error:

```
terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.gitlab_as_attach arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:policy/gitlab_as_policy
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.gitlab_as_attach: Importing from ID "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:policy/gitlab_as_policy"...
Error importing: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.gitlab_as_attach (import id: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:policy/gitlab_as_policy): import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.gitlab_as_attach (id: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:policy/gitlab_as_policy): resource aws_iam_role_policy_attachment doesn't support import
```

terraform version:

```
Terraform v0.11.0
+ provider.aws v1.5.0
```

Comment: There isn't an import for the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` but I don't think you need it either. What happens if you just apply it without having it imported? I guess either it will complain that the role already has the policy attached or, hopefully, that it just completes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue is fixed in 1.37.0 for the provider.aws plugin. Do upgrade the plugins and modules related to the terraform.

To upgrade the plugins run the below command

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

To upgrade the modules run the below command

```
terraform get -update
```

For further information, look up at the defects and enhancements related to terraform

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1370-september-19-2018

I ran import for the aws_iam_role_policy_attachment today and it's successful.

```html
terraform import -provider=aws.{example} aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role-attach-1 {test-role}/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role-attach-1: Importing from ID "{test-role}/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role-attach-1: Import complete!
  Imported aws_iam_role_policy_attachment (ID: {test-role}-arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess)
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role-attach-1: Refreshing state... (ID: {test-role}-arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: aws provider version 1.39: `resource aws_iam_user_policy_attachment doesn't support import`

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I did update the provider version to 0.1.42. But in the document it does say it's been fixed

resource/aws_iam_role_policy_attachment: Support resource import (#5910)

Comment: Still cannot import `aws_iam_policy_attachment` (for access to a VPC, in my case).

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Momooo's response, I was able to import user policy attachment like this:

```
terraform import aws_iam_user_policy_attachment.TERRAFORM_RESOURCE_NAME USER_NAME/POLICY_ARN
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** a [new PR](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/5910) was written and merged, and a new version of the AWS Terraform provider ([1.37.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1370-september-19-2018)) was released adding this feature. This answer is now not really valid anymore; see Momooo's answer for how to do this.

Unfortunately this has been an [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/544) in the AWS Terraform provider for a while, and the [PR that would fix it](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/12101/files) was abandoned. You could try to detach the policy, refresh terraform, perform the import, then re-attach after the import.